# is this bathroom mold a health hazard?

Tags: bathroom, windows, ceiling, mold

Its all over the ceiling. Its really black spots everywhere and its because the awning windows (hinged at bottom) dont provide enough ventialition. The paint is cracking and pealing, i think its supposed to be water-resistant but no use. This is the third time this happened after redoing the ceiling. [image]

Comment: Are you removing all the mold before repainting?  Or are you just repainting on top of it?  The paint failure is indicative of lousy or nonexistent paint prep.  Prep over glossy surfaces requires at least a modest effort in prep.

Answer (score 1):

Though this doesn't seem to be much of a problem at the moment, it can get really bad if you don't **take care of it**. First, I suggest you clean it with normal soap and warm water, and then there are stronger liquids (or other sorts of **detergents**) you can use, but I think normal soap will do the trick (unless you'll **repaint** it later, then use strong detergents). But, this doesn't mean that this won't happen again. So you'll need to remove the moisture problem. Firstly, if possible, check if there are any water pipes inside the ceiling. If there are then make sure they're not **leaking**. Second, try to install a better ventilation system in your bathroom (i.e. air ventilator). Make sure you open doors and **windows** regularly or keep them always open.

Comment: Emphasis on ventilation system. Replacing an old ceiling vent (or installing one outright) will always help with keeping this room dry, even better than opening a window. (I can relate, my home was built without bath vents because of their qualifying openable windows).

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you believe this mold is likely to present a health hazard? I certainly agree that removal and cleaning should occur, though. FWIW, here is a CDC link on mold: https://www.cdc.gov/mold/stachy.htm

Comment: the apartment above me tends to allow leaking into our ceiling but i believe its a ventaliation problem because of the mold as i dont see any moisture on the ceiling.